# Are websockets supported in GraphQL?

Tags: java, java-websocket, graphql-java

Does GraphQL-Java support websockets? It looks like it is not supported. I can't seem to find any information on this, so any help would be very greatly appreciated.

Comment: How are you querying against GraphQL-Java?  I'm not super familiar with the library, but from the docs I don't see any mention of HTTP modules.  If it doesn't meld with HTTP automatically, please show the intersection of you receiving an HTTP request and then interfacing with GraphQL-Java.  I'm thinking you would just swap the HTTP parts for whatever WebSocket implementation you choose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GraphQL runtime tells nothing about the transportation, the only thing is that String is taken as input parameter and the String is the result (part of `graphql.ExecutionResult`) of GraphQL execution.

Take a look on 
`graphql.GraphQL#execute(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.Object, java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.Object>)`